# ServiceStack Authenticate attribute does not checking if user is authenticated

Tags: authentication, servicestack

Im trying to make a service can only be accessed if the client is authenticated and I put the Authenticate attribute but it did not work because when I can access the service without being authenticated. I placed the Authenticate attribute before the Request DTO , top of a service and before the Action. Here is some code of the service I want to secure

```
[Authenticate]
public class HelloService : Service
{
    public const string HelloServiceCounterKey = "HelloServiceCounter";

    public object Any(HelloRequest request)
    {
            var userSession = SessionAs<AppHost.CustomUserSession>();
            Session.Set(HelloServiceCounterKey, Session.Get<int>(HelloServiceCounterKey) + 1);
            var roles = string.Join(", ", userSession.Roles.ToArray());
            return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name + ", your role(s): " + roles };

    }
}
```

I have this in my AppHost Configure(Funq.Container container)

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
           () => new CustomUserSession(),
           new[] { new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider() }
       ));

public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
    {
        public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
        {
            if (!Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password)) return false;

            var session = (CustomUserSession)authService.GetSession(false);
            session.CompanyName = "Company from DB";
            session.UserAuthId = userName;
            session.IsAuthenticated = true;

            // add roles 
            session.Roles = new List<string>();
            if (session.UserAuthId == "admin") session.Roles.Add(RoleNames.Admin);
            session.Roles.Add("User");

            return true;
        }
    }
```

When access the service in the line of

```
var roles = string.Join(", ", userSession.Roles.ToArray());
```

obviosly return NULL because have not been autheticated.

What should do Authenticate attribute on this case?

Answer (score 1):

you need to configure your authentication provider in you app host configuration as follows:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{ 
    Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[]
                {
                 your providers here...
                 }));

}
```

Edit:

Assuming that CustomUserSession inherits from IAuthSession you can change

```
 var session = (CustomUserSession)authService.GetSession(false);
```

To

```
 var session = authService.GetSession<CustomUserSession>();
```

and as far as I see you aren't saving the session after the authentication

try something like this:

```
public override object Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth request)
        {

            string userName = request.UserName;
            string password = request.Password;

            if (!LoginMatchesSession(session, userName))
            {
                authService.RemoveSession();
                session = authService.GetSession();
            }

            if (TryAuthenticate(authService, userName, password))
            {
                authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);
                if (session.UserAuthName == null)
                    session.UserAuthName = userName;
                OnAuthenticated(authService, session, null, null);

                return new AuthResponse
                {
                    UserName = userName,
                    SessionId = session.Id,
                    ReferrerUrl = RedirectUrl
                };
            }

            throw new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "400", "wrong credentials");

        }


  public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
        {
            var session = authService.GetSession<CustomUserSession>();
           if (!Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password)) return false;


                session.IsAuthenticated = true;
                session.Id = authService.GetSessionId();
                return true;


            }
```

**EDIT:**
there's other missing part you need to configure a cacheclient since all the session are managed in cache

try something like that:

```
container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient(){FlushOnDispose = false});
```

can you update your code with your host configuration?

Comment: I have configured my authentication provider as CustomCredentialsAuthProvider and I have added the code to the original question @pedro hope you can help me

Comment: still do not work, I still can access the service without being authenticated @Pedro

Comment: the FlushOnDispose = false inside the constructor of MemoryCacheClient displays an errror, seems there's no constructor of this class with that definition @Pedro

Comment: sorry my mistake is a property set, after the instanciation, new MemoryCacheClient (){ FlushOnDispose = false }